# add a href-link to <li> items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jQuery and I'm looking for a way to do the following:

I have a list of Items:

```
  $.get('../getContent', function(responseJson) { 
      var $ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($('#content'));  
      $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) { 
        $('<li>')
            .text(item)
            .appendTo($ul);
      });
  });
```

I want to make each list item clickable and on click I want to send it's text to a servlet.

Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('<li>')
        .text(item)
        .click(function() {
            $.post(url, {text: item});
        })
        .appendTo($ul);
```

Where `url` is the url of your servlet, and supposing you're posting to it the `text` variable.

Comment: awesome thanks. Do you know of a way I can use the formatting for links I specified in my css as well?

Comment: Sure: `$('<li class="YOUR_CSS_CLASS_HERE">')`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click handler to it

```
$.get('../getContent', function(responseJson) { 
      var $ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($('#content'));  
      $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) { 
        $('<li>')
            .text(item)
            .appendTo($ul)
            .click(function(){
                /* replace alert with servlet code*/
                  alert( $(this).text() );
            });
      });
  });
```